# persistence.xml ignores Hibernate and chooses DataNucleus

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa, datanucleus

I'm toying around with GWT (dunno if this matters) and Hibernate. I've created a a file persistence.xml in META-INF with (amoung) other configuration the line:
org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
But when I startup the EntityManager it chooses DataNucleus instead of Hibernate (which later fails because it isnt installed (jar are not in the class path))

Java Code is:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("gwt");
EntityManager em =factory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transacation = em.getTransaction();
transacation.begin();
Campaign campaign = new Campaign();
campaign.setName("Test");
em.persist(campaign);
transacation.commit();
```

config file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
  version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="gwt" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
  ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other persistence.xml on the class path (sounds weird anyway since you pickup the "gwt" persistence-unit)

Comment: how do you tell it has chosen DataNucleus?

Comment: The Log says:
15:11:48,048  INFO Persistence:77 - DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "1.1.5"
15:11:48,048  INFO Persistence:77 - DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="" driver="" userName=""


It's definitely the right xml file. because when I change "gwt" to something else I get errors much earlier

Comment: I'm starting to guess that I have the wrong JPA/JTA implementation. javax.persistence is defined in a Jar File called: geronimo-jpa.jar. What jar file do I need for Hibernate? I downloaded the entire Hibernate distribution and assumed that the JPA implementation was included (as said on their website). I'm using hibernate 3.5 - could anybody point me to the correct JPA implementation for Hibernate? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong JPA Wrapper classes. I was using geronimo-jpa.jar before and I ended up using the javax-persistance.jar from Glassfish.
Dunno if this is a sweet solution but at least it is one.

Answer (score 0):

So tell me, are you using this on GAE/J ?
DataNucleus is obviously in the CLASSPATH since it is in your log saying just this.

Comment: Yes I'm using this within a Eclipse/GWT Plugin enviroment which afaik emulates an appengine. I'm really new to both hibernate and GWT. I'm running the above script a seperate class with main method and not in context of the appengine though.

Comment: GAE/J Eclipse plugin is for AppEngine and hence BigTable; no idea what a GWT plugin is. Hibernate will not provide persistence to BigTable, clearly. DataNucleus is the only provider for JPA persistence to BigTable. Suggest that you resolve what is your dev environment if not intending on persisting to BigTable

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [Creating a New Web Application](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/creating_new_webapp.html) section from the *Google Plugin for Eclipse* documentation:

> #### Creating a Project with the New Web Application Wizard
>
> The New Web Application Project wizard
> allows you to create a new web
> application that uses Google Web
> Toolkit (GWT) and/or Google App
> Engine:
>
> [image]

Did you select **Use Google App Engine** at project creation time? If yes, don't.